How to import multiple custom JS files into one main 'app.js' file?
I am using Webpack for my website and in my src/js/ I have created three files ; app.js, gsap-animations.js and script.js. My initial idea was to import my other custom js files into one single js file (in this case app.js) just like this :
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----- import node_modules scripts
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

import $ from "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
import gsap from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";


// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----- import custom scripts
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

import "./script.js";
import "./gsap-animations.js";

The first custom file, script.js, loads up fine ; I am using jquery and have functions in there that I can see loaded up on my website. It's clearly doing things. Weirdly enough though, the second custom file, gsap-animations.js, does not ever load. I was just testing around as I am pretty new with GSAP to begin with :
gsap.to('.test-img', {
    ScrollTrigger: '.test-img',
    y: 500,
    duration: 3
});

This is supposed to make my image move on the y axis whenever it comes into the viewport.
After some fiddling around, I realized that if I move the import gsap from "gsap"; AND import scrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger"; INTO gsap-animations.js, IT WORKS. The question is WHY ?
Am I missing something ? Clearly, I use jquery in script.js but have the import $ from "jquery"; in the app.js file, not script.js. I am able to use jquery in script.js just fine though.
So why when it comes to GSAP I have to load it up in the specific file where I am using GSAP ? Am I just too dumb to notice something obvious here ?
Sorry, I know this is pretty newbie. I'm just confused and this is also extremely hard to explain so feel free to ask for clarification.
